# Tabulator: What callback(s) occur after cellEdited?

Tags: javascript, callback, tabulator

I am implementing logic to filter rows based on a `rowState` property in `row.data` {unchanged, changed, new, deleted}.
When a cell is edited, If the row is not a new row, it's `rowState` is changed to 3 (indicating a changed row). `showChanged` is set to `false`, so the row should disappear as soon as `rowState` changes to 3.

At the end of `cellEdited`, I am making a call to `updateFilters()`.
My issue is that the filter is not applying to the row containing the edited cell. I think that this is because the changes to `rowState` don't actually go into effect until the `cellEdited` callback is finished. Is there a callback that occurs after `cellEdited` so that I can effectively apply filtering at the time of edits?

```
  public showOriginal: boolean = true;
  public showChanged: boolean = false;
  public showNew: boolean = false;
  public showDeleted: boolean = false;
  public showNewDeleted: boolean = false;
```

```
private drawTable(): void {
    this.table = new Tabulator(this.tab, {
      rowFormatter: this.rowStateFormatter,
      cellClick:function(e, cell){
        if(!cell.valueAtLoad){
          cell.valueAtLoad = cell._cell.value;
        }
        console.log(cell);
      },
      cellEdited:function(cell){
        
        var row = cell._cell.row;
        var columnName = cell.getColumn()._column.field;
        
        //new Value is different from original value;
        if(cell._cell.value != cell.valueAtLoad){   
          if(!row.changedCells){
            row.changedCells = [];
          }
          row.changedCells.push(columnName);
        }
        //new Value is same as original value;
        else {
          if(row.changedCells){
            if(row.changedCells.find(f => f == columnName)){
              row.changedCells.pop(columnName);
            }
          }
          console.log(row);
        }

        //Set rowState + background Color
        if(row.changedCells.length >= 1){ //If row has changes
          if(!row.data["isNewRow"]) { //if row has changes and is original row
            row.data["rowState"] = 3;
            row.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "#A6A6DF";
          }
        }
        else{
          row.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "";
        }
        this.updateFilters();
      },
      layout: "fitDataStretch",
      movableColumns: true,
      height: "100%",
      pagination: "local",
      paginationSize: 25,
      paginationSizeSelector: [25, 50, 100],
      selectable: true,
      selectableRangeMode: "click",
      data: this.tabRows,
      columns: this.tabHeaders
    });
    document.getElementById(`${this.tableInfo.id}`).appendChild(this.tab);
  }
```

```
private updateFilters(){
    var rowStateFilter = [];
    if(this.showOriginal) {rowStateFilter.push(0); rowStateFilter.push(1)}
    if(this.showNew) {rowStateFilter.push(2)}
    if(this.showChanged) {rowStateFilter.push(3)}
    if(this.showDeleted) {rowStateFilter.push(4)}
    if(this.showNewDeleted) {rowStateFilter.push(5)}
    this.table.setFilter("rowState", "in", rowStateFilter);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the tabulator.js, it looks like :

cell.cellEdited ,table.cellEdited, table.dataChanged

not sure what table.cellEdited is, it looks like a default empty function(). There might be more in the grouping code as well if the cell editing changes that grouping...

```
if (this.column.cellEvents.cellEdited) {
   this.column.cellEvents.cellEdited.call(this.table, component);
}
if (this.table.options.groupUpdateOnCellEdit && this.table.options.groupBy && this.table.modExists("groupRows")) {
   this.table.modules.groupRows.reassignRowToGroup(this.row);
}
this.cellRendered();
this.table.options.cellEdited.call(this.table, component);
if (this.table.options.dataChanged) {
   this.table.options.dataChanged.call(this.table,this.table.rowManager.getData());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which callbacks are fired depends on which modules you have installed on your table *(eg the validation module adds events after edit)*
Luckily, Tabulator comes with debug tools that let you snoop on the events in the console to see which are fired in what order.

Enabling the `debugEventsExternal` option will cause a console log of all external events, so you can see what event is fired when

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    debugEventsExternal:true, //console log external events
});
```

Checkout the [Debug Tools Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.1/debug#events-external) for full details on all the available tools